# Why does my Perl script delete the contents of whole file when I try to edit the file?

Tags: file, perl

I am running the following code to open a file (test) and edit(search and replace) it. Program seems to open the file but instead of replacing it deletes everything in the file. I am not sure why that is happening. Can anyone help me out here?

```
#!use/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = $ARGV[0];
my $find = '\s{6}seqfile\s=\sinfile';
my $replace = '\s{6}seqfile\s=\sinfil2';

open (FILE, ">/home/shubhi/Desktop/pamlrun/test") || die "cant open file \n";
my @body = <FILE>;
foreach $line(@body)
{
(s/$find/$replace/g);
{
print FILE "$line";
}
}
close(FILE);
print "reached here\n";
exit;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your open() is opening a file handle to write to your file. Replace

```
open (FILE, ">/home/shubhi/Desktop/pamlrun/test") || die "cant open file \n";
```

with

```
open (FILE, "/home/shubhi/Desktop/pamlrun/test") || die "cant open file \n";
```

In the code you've posted, it immediately creates this file for output only. You should open the file, read/process the contents, and then write it out. If the file is sizable, then write to a *new* file as you read the old one, and replace the old one upon (successful) completion.

Answer (score 7):

`open(FILE, ">filename")` opens the file in replace mode, writing over whatever there was previously.

Also, you cannot have a regexp in the substitution pattern `$replace`.

If I understood your intent correctly, this could be replaced with an one-liner

```
perl -pi -e 's/(\s{6}seqfile\s=\sinfil)e/${1}2/' /home/shubhi/Desktop/pamlrun/test
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want in-place editing magic.  The easiest way to get this is to use `$^I` with the magic of `@ARGV` plus `<>` (look for null filehandle in the [I/O Operators section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $find = qr/\s{6}seqfile\s=\sinfile/;
my $replace = '      seqfile = infil2';

@ARGV = ("/home/shubhi/Desktop/pamlrun/test");

$^I = ".bak"; #safe the old files as file.bak

while (<>) {
    s/$find/$replace/g;
    print;
}
```

Also, given the nature of your regex, it looks like you probably want `[ ]` (match a space) or `\t` (match a tab) not `\s`.  `\s` will match tabs, spaces, and other whitespace characters.

You can also use [`Tie::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html), but it doesn't seem to provide a backup capability:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my $find = qr/\s{6}seqfile\s=\sinfile/;
my $replace = '      seqfile = infil2';

tie my @lines, "Tie::File", "testdata"
    or die "could not open file: $!";

for my $line (@lines) {
    $line =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
}
```

Of course, you could roll your own backups with [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;
use File::Copy;

my $find = qr/\s{6}seqfile\s=\sinfile/;
my $replace = '      seqfile = infil2';

copy "testdata", "testdata.bak"
    or die "could not backup file: $!";

tie my @lines, "Tie::File", "testdata"
    or die "could not open file: $!";

for my $line (@lines) {
    $line =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
}
```

---

I would also be remiss if I did not point out that this is basically a one-liner:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/\s{6}seqfile\s=\sinfile/      seqfile = infil2/' testdata
```

This can be shortened further with Perl 5.10 by taking advantage of `\K` (zero-width positive look-behind):

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/\s{6}seqfile\s=\s\Kinfile/infil2/' testdata
```

Answer (score 1):

open for write = '>'
open for read = '<'